# Where is the best place to put files for the c# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to know if, for instance, image files should be read from Visual Studio explorer or from bin/debug directory, because applications have resources in the same folder where the executable is. But my project have images in Visual Studio explorer and those files are not put next to the executable, but within the app, because it's not 200 kB but 1500 kB.

Should I continue to put files in Visual Studio explorer and have my bin/debug folder containing one file or put some files in bin/debug folder instead of VS explorer?

I'd like to know because github does not clone bin folder.

I was searching for 30 minutes and I'm not satisfied with the information I've gotten so far. I would like to know if bin folder should contain one file or add some more.

Comment: You should typically include application resources (such as images) in your project and have the build process copy them into the output folder (by changing the properties on the file and changing the "Copy to Output Directory" setting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment: The standard is to put your files under the `source` folder and copy them to the bin folder (or a subfolder thereof) during build, either by the "Copy to Output Directory" setting or, in more complex cases, a post build step. That way, you can put your source folder, together with all resources, under source control, while the bin folder stays ignored. You should not put the bin folder (or parts of it) under source control, as that typically leads to big confusion.

Typically, you'll also only copy the bin folder (as `Program Files\My Application`) to another computer if you want to distribute the application, so if you use a relative path from the exe to the source file via `..\..\source\images\myimage.bmp` that will only work on the development computer.